# How to structure an SQL export combining orders and products

Tags: sql, prestashop

I'm trying to export every order from our Prestashop site, along with the carrier and currency of the order.

I have tried to amend the suggested query given within Prestashop's help section, but I'm coming across various errors including "Undefined 'checkedForm' error"

```
SELECT o.id_order AS id,
   CONCAT(LEFT(c.firstname, 1), . , c.lastname) AS Customer,
    ca.name AS Carrier,
    cu.name AS Currency,
    o.payment, CONCAT(o.total_paid_real,  , cu.sign) AS Total,
    o.date_add AS Date
 FROM prstshp_orders o
 LEFT JOIN prstshp_customer c ON (o.id_customer = c.id_customer)
 LEFT JOIN prstshp_carrier ca ON (o.id_carrier = ca.id_carrier)
 LEFT JOIN prstshp_currency cu ON (o.id_currency = cu.id_currency)
```

Each database referred to exists, as do the fields. Because of the errors, no data is exported at all so I'm unable to give info on the actual results. The expected results would be a CSV file with the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

These are highly suspicious:

```
CONCAT(LEFT(c.firstname, 1), . , c.lastname) AS Customer,
CONCAT(o.total_paid_real,  , cu.sign) AS Total
```

Presumably, you intend:

```
CONCAT(LEFT(c.firstname, 1), '.', c.lastname) AS Customer,
CONCAT(o.total_paid_real, cu.sign) AS Total
```

I don't know if there are other errors.